# Return type of collection.find in mongodb using java

Tags: java, mongodb, maven

I am trying to implement a simple login function using java where a user enters a username and password through a text field and then these credentials are checked against a set of documents in a collection in mongodb, using maven dependencies.
The connection with the database has been made and relevant imports added.

```
import com.mongodb.client.FindIterable;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.and;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.eq;

String user  = txtUser.getText();
String pass = txtPass.getText();

MongoDatabase db = DbConnection.getDbConnection();
MongoCollection collection = db.getCollection("Admin");
FindIterable<Document> findLogin = collection.find(and(eq("username", user),eq("password",pass)));

if(findLogin == null){
     System.out.println("Failed");
}else{
      System.out.println("Successful");
}
```

The problem here is that successful is displayed even when the wrong credentials are entered. This is my first time using mongodb so I am not entirely sure of the queries that can be run on mongodb. What type of value does the collection.find return. And what are the possible methods I could follow to overcome the problem?

Comment: you understand that the code you posted can not be compiled, so shouldn't be used as an example of your issue here.

Answer (score 0):

The [FindIterable](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/apidocs/mongodb-driver-sync/com/mongodb/client/FindIterable.html) returned by the [find()](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/apidocs/mongodb-driver-sync/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#find(org.bson.conversions.Bson)) method of MongoCollection will not be `null`. In order to determine whether any documents were matched by your query, you need to inspect the `FindIterable`.

In your case, the [first()](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/apidocs/mongodb-driver-sync/com/mongodb/client/MongoIterable.html#first()) method is the most appropriate. This way you get a single document to perform a null check on. Put all together it may look like this:

```java
Document loginDoc = collection.find(and(eq("username", user),eq("password",pass))).first();

if (loginDoc == null) {
     System.out.println("Failed");
} else {
     System.out.println("Successful");
}
```